# Firefox version >56 I can see traffics in Real Time but not in any report or dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

Please find the javascript code that I am using to track the analytics for dialog.html page of my extension.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-********-1']);
var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
ga.async = true;
ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

var trackPage = function () {

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open("POST", "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", true);

let message ="v=1&tid=" + "UA-**********-1" + "&cid= " + "*********" + "&aip=1" +"&ds=add-on&t=pageview&dp="+"dialog.html"+"&dt="+"TruePath-Home";

request.send(message);
}


function setDOMInfo() 
   {

    if (browser_version>55 && browser_name==='Firefox' ){
        trackPage();
    }
    else{
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    }
   }
```

Since newer version of Firefox don't allow the tracking so I wrote the custom code for tracking.The setDOMInfo function is kicked off on loading the dialog.html.

I have observed that for Firefox version >56 I can see traffics in Real Time but not in any report or dashboard.

Comment: You may need to wait up to 24 hours for the info to appear anywhere other than Real Time, or have you already done that?

Comment: I have already waited 24 hours.Somehow I believe this custom code trackPage() is failed to insert the data to use in reports although it is working for realtime traffic

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to figure out this issue why it is not updating the analytics for the Firefox version>56.

We need to pass userAgent info along with the request. The javascript code to retrieve userAgent as shown below: 
var data = navigator.userAgent;

So your code would be

```
var trackPage = function () {
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = navigator.userAgent;
request.open("POST", "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", true);
let message ="v=1&tid=" + "UA-**********-1" + "&cid= " + "*********" + "&aip=1" +"&ds=add-on&t=pageview&dp="+"dialog.html"+"&dt="+"TruePath-Home"+"&ua="+data;

request.send(message);
```

}